# Neural network does not proceed/delivers no output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

A college passed me his code for a neural network. I want to train the network to recognize if an image is a technical drawing or something else. Because the test csv-file is around 14GB I had no other choice but to implement a chunkwise read-in method with pandas. Sadly, after doing so the neural network does not seem to work anymore. My python shell tells me, that the program has started but does not deliver anything. I waited about an hour without any progress. Since, there is no sign on my RAM or processor in the Task-Manager working on a heavy task I suggest something does not work properly. Since I do not get an error message feel completely lost what to do next.
  The code looks like this :

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from tqdm import tqdm
import csv
import pandas as pd

class neuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inode = inputnodes
        self.hnode = hiddennodes
        self.onode = outputnodes
# =============================================================================
#         self.wih=np.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.inode,-0.5),(self.hnode,self.inode))
#         self.who=np.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnode,-0.5),(self.onode,self.hnode))
# =============================================================================
        self.wih = np.random.normal(0, pow(self.hnode, -0.5), (self.hnode, self.inode))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0, pow(self.onode, -0.5), (self.onode, self.hnode))
        self.lr = learningrate
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        pass

    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        output_errors = targets - final_outputs
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors) 
        self.who += self.lr * np.dot((output_errors * final_outputs 
        * (1.0 - final_outputs)), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))
        self.wih += self.lr * np.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs 
        * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)), np.transpose(inputs))
        pass

    def test(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        return final_outputs

input_nodes = 784
hidden_nodes = 500
output_nodes = 10
learning_rate = 0.1
epochs = 5
chunksize = 10**8

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes, learning_rate)
#training_data_file = open('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/train.csv', 'r')
#training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
#training_data_file.close()

for e in range(epochs):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/train.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
        process(chunk)
    for record in tqdm(get_chunk()): # train on this record
        all_values = record.split(',')
        inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
        targets = np.zeros(output_nodes) + 0.01
        targets[int(float(all_values[0]))] = 0.99
        n.train(inputs, targets)
        pass
    pass

#test_data_file = open('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/test.csv', 'r')
#test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines()
#test_data_file.close()

scorecard = []

for record in test_data_list:
    for chunk in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/test.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
        process(chunk)
    for record in tqdm(get_chunk()):
        all_values = record.split(',')
        correct_label = int(all_values[0])
        inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
        outputs = n.test(inputs)
        label = np.argmax(outputs)
    if (label == correct_label):
        scorecard.append(1)
    else:
        scorecard.append(0)
        pass
    pass

scorecard_array = np.asarray(scorecard)
print ("Genauigkeit = ", scorecard_array.sum() / scorecard_array.size)
```

Comment: This is a large amount of code to ask someone to debug. You should try to create a [mre]

Comment: Yes. In the year 2019 it is a good idea to use untested neural code network you whacked together from some linear algebra functions instead of one of the many mature libraries for that purpose. That's a mighty fine wheel you've reinvented - have you considered making it round instead of square?

Comment: To be honest. I would be even fine if I would have known about those libraries. I'am an absolute beginner in python, which seems quite obvious, still I need to finish this project. I thought the easiest way would be to use a code which already worked before. So, if there is a library with two or three simple functions, to create a neural network, I would be appreciate any tips to solve the stated problem (a neural network which recognizes technical drawings).